# Python Eve patch_internal set etag

Tags: python, flask, eve

I am trying to make an `on_insert` event hook for a document from schema A, call eve's `patch_internal` to a document from schema B.

Since the request triggering the event hook is a `POST` for A, there's no `If-Match` header with the necessary B `etag` in flask request.

I've tried to set the value on the flask request before the `patch_internal` with `flask.request.if_match`, but seems it is not possible since it is a frozenset.

How can I set the `etag` for the `patch_internal` call?

In summary, the creation of a document updates other document with different schema. Can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say this is the best way, but it works.

Creating a new request context to call `patch_internal`, and setting the `etag` on the `environ` used to create it, works. Below an example:

```
from flask import request, current_app
from eve.methods.patch import patch_internal

...

new_environ = request.environ
new_env['HTTP_IF_MATCH'] = patched_document['_etag']
    with current_app.request_context(new_env):
        result = patch_internal('my_document_b', {'updated_key': value},  {'_id': my_document_b['_id']})
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `concurrency_check=False` in your call to `patch_internal`

```
from eve.methods.patch import patch_internal

with app.request_context():
   payload = {"value_key": "new value"}
   lookup = {"_id": "12ababa12..."}
   patch_internal("res_name", payload, **lookup, concurrency_check=False)
```

Comment: This is a good idea! But to be in the safe side in my case I believe it is good to keep concurrency control enabled.